# computing multiple covariance matrices

Tags: numpy, covariance

I have a matrix `X` of size `(1875, 77)`. For each column, I want to compute the covariance matrix, i.e., `x_1 @ x_1.T` where `x_1` has a shape `(1875, 1)`. Ideally, I want to do this in one-go without a for loop. Is there an easy way to do this?

I was thinking about padding with zeros for each column up and down based on the column index(so `x_1` will have 76 zeros columns, `x_2` will have one `(77, 1)` zero column pad on top and 75 zero column pads), but this seems to complicate things more.

Comment: You just want 77 of those matrices right? Like 77 `1875 x 1875` shaped matrices?

Comment: @swag2198 yeah, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
import numpy as np
r, c = 1875, 77
X = np.random.rand(r, c)
covs = X.T[..., None] @ X.T[:, None, :]
covs.shape
# (77, 1875, 1875)
```

This simply performs `c` number of matrix multiplications, 1 for each column of `X`. Here `X.T[..., None]` is of shape *(c, r, 1)* and `X.T[:, None, :]` is of shape *(c, 1, r)* and this makes the matrix multiple between them compatible.